# Computing orders of some irreducible finite Coxeter groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, root-systems, coxeter-groups

There is a particular method in *Reflection groups and Coxeter groups* by Humphreys to compute the orders of various irreducible finite Coxeter groups in Chapter 2.11. The method involves using group action of a finite group $G$ acting as a permutation group on a set $X \ni x$ so that $|G|=|Gx||G_x|$, where $Gx$ is the orbit of $x$ and $G_x$ is the isotropy group of $x$.

In the context of irreducible finite Coxeter groups $W$, $W$ acts on the root system $\Phi$. The main exercise in that section asks to compute the orders of groups of type $\mathrm{A}_n$, $\mathrm{B}_n$, and $\mathrm{D}_n$ ($\mathrm{A}_n$ is not the alternating group of order $n!/2$ and $\mathrm{D}_n$ is not the dihedral group of order $2n$).

My question is, how can we figure out the orbits and isotropy groups for the groups in the exercise? I'm finding it trickier to do this for the groups of type $\mathrm{B}_n$ and $\mathrm{D}_n$. Also, even though I know that the group of type $\mathrm{A}_n$ is the symmetric group $S_{n+1}$ of order $(n+1)!$, I'm not entirely sure how to end up with this order using the above suggested method. Are there any good references I could use?

Comment: How are the root systems presented to you?

Comment: For A$_n$, $\Phi_{1}$ contains vectors $\epsilon_{i}-\epsilon_{j}, 1 \leq i \neq j \leq n+1$, and so $|\Phi_{1}|=n(n+1)$. For B$_n$, $\Phi_{2}$ contains $2n$ short roots $\pm \epsilon_{i}$ and $2n(n-1)$ long roots $\pm \epsilon_{i} \pm \epsilon_{j}, i<j$ so that $|\Phi_{2}|=2n^2$. Finally for D$_n$, $\Phi_{3}$ contains $2n(n-1)$ roots $\pm \epsilon_{i} \pm \epsilon_{j}, 1 \leq i<j \leq n$ so that $|\Phi_{3}|=2n(n-1)$.

Comment: For $A_n$ for example the action is transitive if you pick $\epsilon_{n}-\epsilon_{n+1}$ and the isotropy group is $A_{n-2}$.

Comment: So in the case for A$_n$, would $\Phi_{1}$ be the orbit space?

Comment: Yes. And the action on roots of a fixed length is transitive in other types.

Comment: It's transitive on the long roots and transitive on the short roots.

Comment: But a long root can't be sent to a short root.

Comment: What would the isotropy group be for B$_n$? Only the simple root $\alpha_{2}= \epsilon_{2}-\epsilon_{3}$ is not orthogonal to the highest (long) root $\tilde{\alpha}= \epsilon_{1} + \epsilon_{2}$.

Comment: The "best" choice of simple roots is not so obvious for $B_n$, and I seem to recall some of the older books choosing simple roots that don't relate $B_n$ with $B_{n-1}$ very well. By your comment, it seems that this book has made that choice.

Comment: Been very busy and I don't know this off the top of my head, and I don't really have time to work it out. The best skill you can cultivate though is persevering even though you're stuck, because you'll get stuck all the time in research. Take a break, do something entertaining for an hour or so, then try again. You'll often have new ideas.